# PHP unable to include other PHP files

Tags: php, include, internal-server-error

I've playing with a very simple setup: index.php with a header.php in the same directory. I've tried all the ways to include the header.php into my index.php but I still get a 500 - Internal Server Error.

So I tried the most fool-proof method and only coded this into my index.php

```
<?php
include("http://mywebsite.com/header.php"); 
echo "index";
?>
```

Then in my header.php I only coded

```
<?php echo "header"; ?>
```

I cannot figure out whats causing the problem. I've included an absolute path to the header. When I remove the include function the 500 error is no longer an issue.

I'm running my site using GoDaddy with a Plesk/Windows platform if that makes any difference?

Comment: RTFM: If the header.php is in the same directory as the index.php then remove domain name. Only file name like `include("header.php");`  is enough. [More](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/header.php";
   include_once($path);
?>
```

see: [PHP include absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912121/php-include-absolute-path)

Comment: That's interesting, although I think I'd tried this before it seems to have worked. I've echoed $path and I got a rather different looking path beginning with the drive letter.

Comment: Sometimes, even the smallest details make all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Contents of index.php:

```
<?php 
include 'header.php';
echo 'index';
?>
```

Contents of header.php:

```
echo 'header';
```