# PHP - No such file or directory (LAMP server)

Tags: php, linux, apache, server, lamp

I've been on this bug for too long so I'm looking for some help from more experienced server programmers.

I'm running a Bitnami LAMP stack. I'm trying to use a PHP script (maintenance.php) to move files on the server. So I'm using `rename(filepath, newpath)` in my script. However, the PHP script cannot find the file even though it exists on the server.

SOLVED: The problem was that I was calling the script from two different places during debug (my browser, and my linux shell). The "working directory" in each of these places was different so the filepaths represented different locations depending on where I called the PHP script from.

Comment: Leave off the beginning `/`

Comment: Already tried. >>

rename(pictures/CA/Ontario/Waterloo/564409b235bd29.29353255.jpg,archive/CA/Ontario/Waterloo/564409b235bd29.29353255.jpg): No such file or directory

Comment: Then use an absolute pathname

Comment: how? doesn't it always start from the working directory

Answer (score 1):

There is no `pictures` directory at root so `/pictures` wont work.
Instead you will have to use absolute path to the `pictures` directory.

There are multiple ways to do this.

You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which will give you `root directory under which the current script is executing`.

[reserved.variables.server](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Also, you can use `__FILE__` which will give you the path to current file.
With `dirname(__FILE__)` you can get directory and then you can work up to the pictures directory by going level down using `../`.

This is also a similar question that you can check,

[PHP include absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912121/php-include-absolute-path)

Comment: I'm making progress now. I was majorly confused because I was running the php script from my browser as well as the shell and the working directories were different for each. Thanks for your help.